# Examples of distance "hyperparameters" used in clustering

Tags: clustering, distance, hierarchical-data-format, manifold

From what I've seen in clustering, distance is taken as a hyper parameter (which is to be selected) when inferring the relationships/clusters between points.

What are some examples of highly-cited papers doing this, and is there any concrete empirical evidence supporting this practice?